# How to execute directly the base class of the inheritance chain in Javascript (OOP)?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm working with the inheritance chain of 3 extendable classes. 
*Renderer (Base) -> Mailbox (Child) -> MailboxInbox (final child)*

Each of them has it's own `render` method. Child's just override the Renderer (Base) `render` method At the end they anyway should use the `render` method of the **Renderer** (**Base**) class. My problem that when I'm executing some method in the **Renderer** class (*createElementWithTextInside*) it doesn't execute exactly the **Renderer's render** method (Renderer.render()) but it rather starts for the end of the extendable class chaing. Eg it starts to walk through: 
1 - `MailboxInbox.render` 
2 - `Mailbox.render` 
3 - `Renderer.render`

I understand how js classes/inheritance works  under the hood. Javascript just extends objects prototypes and the script walks through them etc. but my question: How to avoid this behavior and directly call the **Renderer.render** method inside it's method when I need to?

I can't save **__self** in the **Renderer**  because it will be anyway pointing to `this` the current instance (MailboxInbox). Also I can't use **.bind/lambda (arrow function)** because I need to save the context

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/velidan/zvf8uh7y/13/)

```
    class Renderer {
    
      get noResultContent() {
        const p = this.createElement('p', 'no-result-msg');
        const textNode = document.createTextNode('No result');
        p.appendChild(textNode);
    
        return p;
      };
    
    
    
      createElement(tag, className) {
        if (!tag) throw new Error('Tag must be passed!');
    
        const res = document.createElement(tag);
        res.classList.add(className);
        return res;
      }
      
      createTextNode(text) {
        const res = document.createTextNode(text);
        return res;
      }
    
      /**
       * automatically creates an el based on tag, text node and insert the text node into the el
       */
      createElementWithTextInside(tag, className, content) {
    
        const el = this.createElement(tag, className);
        const text = this.createTextNode(content);
        this.render(el, text);
    
        return el;
      }
      
      checkIfDomEl = el => el instanceof Element;
    
    
      render(el, content) {

        console.log('3: RENDERER RENDER')
        if (!this.checkIfDomEl(el)) throw new Error(`Please, pass the valid DOM el. Received: ${el}, ${typeof el} `);
    
        const finalContent = content || this.noResultContent;
        
        el.appendChild(finalContent);
      }
    
    }
    --------
    class Mailbox extends Renderer {
      rootEl;
    
      
    
      constructor(selector) {
        super();
        this.rootEl = document.querySelector(selector);
      }
    
      renderTitle(content) {
        if (!content) return null;
    
        const titleEl = super.createElementWithTextInside('h3', 'mailbox-title', content)
    
        super.render(this.rootEl, titleEl);
    
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log('2: MAILBOX RENDER')
        super.render(this.rootEl);
      }
    }
    --------
    class MailboxInbox extends Mailbox {
    
      title = "Inbox"
    
      constructor(params) {
       const { selector } = params;
       super(selector); 
      }
    
      renderTitle() {
        super.renderTitle(this.title);
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log('1: INBOX RENDER')
        super.render();
      }
    }
--------
const inbox = new MailboxInbox({selector: '#container'}); 
inbox.renderTitle()
```

Here it just renders in console:
**1: INBOX RENDER 

2: MAILBOX RENDER 

3: RENDERER RENDER**

Thanks for any help!
Kind regards!

*Update* 
Basically I just wanted to have a basic `render` class that could accept arguments: `(el,content)` (content is optional) and in the *Children* I wanted to overrided it in their own `.render()` methods with some predefined `el` and `content` etc. but if I try to execute `renderer.render()` method from inside the **Renderer**, it walks through the whole chain and my arguments are lost because in **MailboxInbox** the render method currently doesn't accept any arguments so I either should make it to accept the arguments and pass them through the whole chain or just define in **Renderer** some dedicated class like `baseRender` and call it directly

Comment: I'm not sure if any existing programming language allows what you want to do

Comment: "*How to avoid this behavior and directly call the `Renderer.render` method inside it's method when I need to?*" - why do need to? Is the `render` method of the current instance doing something wrong? Then maybe you should rethink whether your inheritance hierarchy is correct.

Comment: @Velidan ... what's wrong with the current, above presented, implementation?

Comment: @Konrad JavaScript absolutely lets you do it

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I think you're right because I fiil that there is something wrong with this approach. I think I should create some dedicated `baseRender` method and just call it separatedly.  P.S. I updated the question and described why I'm trying to handle this stuff

Comment: @PeterSeliger, I've just updated the post with the description of why I'm trying to handle it, please, check it

Comment: @Velidan ... The entire point of a forwarding cascade, here via `super.render`, is that the implementer can decide at which point which parameters are going to be passed. Thus, within both of the child-/grandchild implementations the implementer has to take care of the correct parameters. Can you think of how to utilize the forwarding approach in terms of the entire modeling? Any answer is valid. In case the forwarding doesn't make any sense, it is, as _Bergi_ already did mention, an indicator for a not that well designed inheritance model.

Answer (score 0):

> How to directly execute a base class method, ignoring the inheritance chain, in Javascript?

You can technically replace `this.render(el, text);` by

```
Renderer.prototype.render.call(this, el, text);
```

which circumvents the inherited property lookup. However, this is not a good practice in general, forfeiting the `class` inheritance advantages.

Fortunately, you already identified the actual problem in your update:

> my arguments are lost because in `MailboxInbox`, the `render` method currently doesn't accept any arguments

This does incorrectly override the method with an incompatible signature, breaking the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

And you already identified the potenial solutions as well:

> I either should make it to accept the arguments and pass them through the whole chain, or just define in `Renderer` some dedicated method like `baseRender` and call that directly

Both are fine. In the latter, instead of naming the methods `render` and `baseRender`, I would recommend something like `renderContent(el, content)` and `renderDefault(el)`, which actually differ in their signature - and which could both be overridden. However, looking at the implementation of `render` when called with two arguments, it imo doesn't really do anything useful other than calling `el.appendChild(content)`, so I'd rather drop it entirely and just call `appendChild` (unless you need the ability to override the concreted behaviour, e.g. by doing `el.prepend(content)` instead).

Comment: I'm really curious about the reason of leaving an even uncommented -1vote. The above answer does not show/contain any technical faults. On the contrary, it sheds light from different angles of view on the problem and provides reasonable explanations.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood the OP asked how to call `Renderer::render()` with `super.render()` in `MailboxInbox::render()` **WHILE** extending `MailboxInbox` from `Mailbox`.

So answering. How to improve the OP's code is just another question which is out of the answer's scope. I'm using the OP's original code here without modifications.

Bergi's pointed to the error, but it isn't related directly to the OP's question. The OP should fix the `MailboxInbox::render()` to provide proper arguments to `Renderer::render()`.

So to the anwer:

Javascript allows to build any prototype chain you want.
In our case we extend our `MailboxInbox` with `Renderer` but then we inject a limited `Mailbox` class version without `render` method between `MailboxInbox` and `Renderer`. So the `render` starts working as you wanted. The question is whether it's right to do is just another one. I've just shown a way how your prototype chain could be made.

```js
function injectParentClass(destinationClass, parentClass, removeProps = []){

  // remove props from the prototype

  const proto = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(parentClass.prototype);
  
  removeProps.forEach(prop => delete proto[prop]);
  delete proto.constructor;

  // make `super` working in the destinationClass
  const injectedPrototype = function(){
    const factory = parentClass.bind(this);
    new factory(...arguments);
  }
  
  // copy the remaining props to the injected prototype
  for(const k in proto){
    Object.defineProperty(injectedPrototype, k, proto[k]);
  }
  
  // make the injection
  const parentPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(destinationClass.prototype);

  Object.setPrototypeOf(destinationClass.prototype, injectedPrototype);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(injectedPrototype, parentPrototype);

}

injectParentClass(MailboxInbox, Mailbox, ['render']);


const mailbox = new Mailbox('#container'); 
mailbox.renderTitle('Mailbox title')

const inbox = new MailboxInbox({selector: '#container'}); 
inbox.renderTitle()
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
class Renderer {

  get noResultContent() {
    const p = this.createElement('p', 'no-result-msg');
    const textNode = document.createTextNode('No result');
    p.appendChild(textNode);

    return p;
  };



  createElement(tag, className) {
    if (!tag) throw new Error('Tag must be passed!');

    const res = document.createElement(tag);
    res.classList.add(className);
    return res;
  }

  createTextNode(text) {
    const res = document.createTextNode(text);
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * automatically creates an el based on tag, text node and insert the text node into the el
   */
  createElementWithTextInside(tag, className, content) {

    const el = this.createElement(tag, className);
    const text = this.createTextNode(content);
    this.render(el, text);

    return el;
  }

  checkIfDomEl = el => el instanceof Element;


  render(el, content) {

    console.log('3: RENDERER RENDER')
    if (!this.checkIfDomEl(el)) throw new Error(`Please, pass the valid DOM el. Received: ${el}, ${typeof el} `);

    const finalContent = content || this.noResultContent;

    el.appendChild(finalContent);
  }

}

class Mailbox extends Renderer {

  rootEl;

  constructor(selector) {
    super();
    this.rootEl = document.querySelector(selector);
  }

  renderTitle(content) {
    if (!content) return null;

    const titleEl = super.createElementWithTextInside('h3', 'mailbox-title', content)

    super.render(this.rootEl, titleEl);

  }

  render() {
    console.log('2: MAILBOX RENDER')
    super.render(this.rootEl);
  }
}

class MailboxInbox extends Renderer {

  title = "Inbox"

  constructor(params) {
   const { selector } = params;
   super(selector); 
  }

  renderTitle() {
    super.renderTitle(this.title);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('1: INBOX RENDER')
    super.render();
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why is `injectedPrototype` a function?

Comment: @Bergi we need to make `super(selector)` working in the `MailboxInbox::constructor()`. if you know the better way, please elaborate, i'm just as always in hurry ;-)

Comment: @Bergi we need some proxy constructor in the `injectedPrototype` to forward `super` calls in the `MailboxInbox::constructor`

Comment: `super()` in the `destinationClass` constructor is only affected if you were to set the prototype of `destinationClass`, not the prototype of `destinationClass.prototype`. The prototype objects should be non-callable objects.

Comment: Btw, this approach doesn't even work, it does not address the OP's problem. The snippet still throws an exception because `MailboxInbox.prototype.render` does not accept and forward arguments.

Comment: this `super()` should call the constructor of `Mailbox`. If you know a better way how to do that, please tell me, i just didn't have time to search for alternatives. otherwise it works fine, the result is as expected

Comment: @Bergi it's because there's no HTML. The methods are called as the OP asked. The error isn't related to the OP's problem

Comment: @Bergi also the OP calling the inbox with no element content, so everything is ok with my code

Comment: "*`super()` should call the constructor of `Mailbox`.*" - even then, it doesn't do that, because you injected `injectedPrototype` into the prototype of `destinationClass.prototype` not `destinationClass` itself

Comment: "*also the OP calling the inbox with no element content*" - and that's the actual problem they have that needs to be addressed. Injecting things into the prototype chain does not actually help with that.

Comment: @Bergi the OP asked how to call `Renderer::render()` with `super.render()` in `MailboxInbox::render()` WHILE extending `MailboxInbox` from `Mailbox` which I did. That was the main exact question the OP asked. How to improve the code is just another question. I was answering the exact question the OP asked.

Comment: @Bergi i've updated the answer with all remarks in the comments here, maybe it would clarify my answer

Comment: No. They're asking how to call `Renderer::render` from `Renderer::createElementWithTextInside` (in a way that still works when calling `createElementWithTextInside` on an instance of `Mailbox` or `MailboxInbox`). Please re-read the question.

Comment: @Bergi read it several times: At the end they anyway should use the render method of the Renderer (Base) class. My problem that when I'm executing some method in the Renderer class (createElementWithTextInside) it doesn't execute exactly the Renderer's render method

Comment: @Bergi about the error and your understanding of the answer: Bergi's pointed to the error, but it isn't related directly to the OP's question. The OP should fix the `MailboxInbox::render()` to provide proper arguments to `Renderer::render()`.

Comment: …and once they've done that, they no longer need the prototype injection from your answer.

Comment: @Bergi that's trivial, i wanted to exercise :)